# Want to show different date (time) in each HTML element and date(time) should be changed automatically to latest after some time

Tags: jquery, html, date

I have some HTML fields and I'm able to get current date(time) in these fields, but I want to show different time in each element as like showing in any comment system. Below is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
    <span>Here I'm heading One!</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <span>Here I'm heading Two!</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <span>Here I'm heading Three!</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <span>Here I'm heading Four!</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <span>Here I'm heading Five!</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

And I'm able to get current date in each second span with the help of below jQuery:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(){
var now = new Date(), // current date
    months = ['January', 'February', 'March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']; // added all the months
    time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(), // get time

    // a cleaner way than string concatenation
    date = [now.getDate(), 
            months[now.getMonth()],
            now.getFullYear()].join(' ');
    $('.inner span:nth-child(2)').html([date, time].join(' at ')); });
```

My issue is, I want to show different time in each second span somewhat like as below:

Here I'm heading One! 15 June 2017 at 1:55:40
Here I'm heading Two! 15 June 2017 at 10:55:30
Here I'm heading Three! 14 June 2017 at 2:55:20
Here I'm heading Four! 13 June 2017 at 1:30:50
Here I'm heading Five! 12 June 2017 at 1:55:50

But now its showing current date and time.

I want it to time difference between each element like 2 or 3 hours and will change accordingly, like now First heading time is 15 June 2017 at 1:55:40 and it should change automatically after 3 hours to latest time and so on other fields as well to latest date(time).

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research into how to add hours to a Date object. Maybe with [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)... You might also look into [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for formatting the dates and times. For the update, look into [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I will try these functions to achieve this, I hope someone will help me on this as need this to done urgently soon